# Parsing text file into NSArray but how do I extract it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsarray

I have this code

```
NSArray *wordListArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
[[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@”sowpods” ofType:@”txt”]
encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding error:NULL] componentsSeparatedByString:@”\n”]];
```

My question is how can I extract this text and update a label in a Scrollview? I just need the user to be able to scroll down and read whats in the text file...

Comment: What do you mean by "extract"? What do you want the scroll view to show? You could use a table view, which is a type of scroll view.
Table views are populated by means of a data source. Have you read the api for the UITableViewDataSource protocol?

Comment: I don't think Tableview is what I'm after I just need the app to read from the text file and output to a label in a scrollview. its just a tutorial app so I need the user to be able to scroll down and read the text thats all... Sorry if I'm not making much sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you want to do is something like:

```
CGRect appFrame = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]frame];
UIScrollView* scrollView = [[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:appFrame] autorelease];
CGRect lblFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, scrollView.frame.size.width, 20.0f);
for (NSString* word in wordListArray)
{
  UILabel* lbl = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lblFrame]autorelease];
  lbl.text = word;
  [scrollView addSubview:lbl];
  lblFrame.origin.y += 20.0f;
}
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(lblFrame.size.width, lblFrame.origin.y);
[mainView addSubview:scrollView];  // mainView = up to you
```

(NB: I haven't tested this, could contain errors, but just want to give you ideas to work with.)